# Possible bug in 1.7 import for saving product qty in function _saveStockItem()

Tags: import, bug, cataloginventory

I had a problem where product import files with only `sku` and `qty` fields were importing the wrong qty's for most items. I realized that whatever `qty` the first item had would be applied to all the rest of the items.

I managed to fix it. I'm not sure if it's actually a bug or may be caused by some extension I am using, but I thought I would report it here and see if anyone has heard of this.

I located the problem in `class Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product extends Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Abstract` `protected function _saveStockItem()`.

It appears that the $row variable is created with this line in loop 1:

```
$row['product_id'] = $this->_newSku[$rowData[self::COL_SKU]]['entity_id'];
```

But on the next loop, the `$row` variable is not reset and retains data from the previous item.

Here is the part of the function I am looking at:

```
while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
        $stockData = array();

        // Format bunch to stock data rows
        foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
            if (!$this->isRowAllowedToImport($rowData, $rowNum)) {
                continue;
            }
            // only SCOPE_DEFAULT can contain stock data
            if (self::SCOPE_DEFAULT != $this->getRowScope($rowData)) {
                continue;
            }
            $row = array(); // ADDED THIS LINE TO FIX POSSIBLE BUG
            $row['product_id'] = $this->_newSku[$rowData[self::COL_SKU]]['entity_id'];
            $row['stock_id'] = 1;

            /** @var $stockItem Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item */
            $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
            $stockItem->loadByProduct($row['product_id']);
            $existStockData = $stockItem->getData();

            }
            $row = array_merge(
                $defaultStockData,
                array_intersect_key($existStockData, $defaultStockData),
                array_intersect_key($rowData, $defaultStockData),
                $row
            );
            $stockItem->setData($row);
            // ETC...
            // ...
            // ...
        }
}
```

Below is the same section of code from Magento 1.5. It also does not reset the variable using `$row = array()`, but for some reason it avoids the problem it's having in 1.7:

```
while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
        $stockData = array();

        foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
            if (!$this->isRowAllowedToImport($rowData, $rowNum)) {
                continue;
            }
            // only SCOPE_DEFAULT can contain stock data
            if (self::SCOPE_DEFAULT == $this->getRowScope($rowData)) {
                $row = array_merge(
                    $defaultStockData,
                    array_intersect_key($rowData, $defaultStockData)
                );
                $row['product_id'] = $this->_newSku[$rowData[self::COL_SKU]]['entity_id'];
                $row['stock_id'] = 1;
                /** @var $stockItem Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item */
                $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item', $row);

                if ($helper->isQty($this->_newSku[$rowData[self::COL_SKU]]['type_id'])) {
                    if ($stockItem->verifyNotification()) {
                        $stockItem->setLowStockDate(Mage::app()->getLocale()
                            ->date(null, null, null, false)
                            ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT)
                        );
                    }
                    $stockItem->setStockStatusChangedAutomatically((int) !$stockItem->verifyStock());
                } else {
                    $stockItem->setQty(0);
                }
                $stockData[] = $stockItem->getData();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right, it's a bug.

Replace the following lines:

```
$row = array_merge(
    $defaultStockData,
    array_intersect_key($existStockData, $defaultStockData),
    array_intersect_key($rowData, $defaultStockData),
    $row
);
```

with

```
$row = array_merge(
    $row,
    $defaultStockData,
    array_intersect_key($existStockData, $defaultStockData),
    array_intersect_key($rowData, $defaultStockData)
);
```

in `app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php`. Of course, you should do a rewrite and not modify the core file directly as the change would be gone with the next update.

Comment: Hi Andreas. It seems you are using the fact that `array_merge`'s later arguments overwrite earlier arguments with the same keys, such that earlier arguments can act as "defaults". So it makes sense to put `$row` first. Is your solution better than my idea to reset `$row` to `$row = array()`?